# How to express this sequence $a_n$ in math notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I express this sequence $a_n$ in math notation where each pair $(x,y)$ is coprime?

**Examples**

$a_2=\{(1,1)\}$

$a_3=\{(1, 2), (2, 1)\}$

$a_5=\{(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)\}$

$a_7=\{(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4), (4, 3), (5, 2), (6, 1)\}$

...

I tried this...

$a_{n}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb N_{\gt 0}^2, \gcd(x,y)=1 : x+y=n\}$

Thanks.

Comment: instead of using $n$ odd, you can also write $2n+1$ and start your indexing from 0

Comment: A sequence should also be defined for even indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is fine.
For prime $n$ this is equivalent, and perhaps easier to read.

$$
a_n = \{(k, n-k) \, | \, 1 \le k < n\}
$$

If you want it for arbitrary $n$,
$$
a_n = \{(k, n-k) \, | \, 1 \le k < n\text{ and } \gcd(k, n-k) = 1\} .
$$